# What is Javascript Event Listener's scope?

Tags: javascript

In C, if I don't dynamically malloc Anything inside a function, it is free'd when the function ends. I have no clue how Javascript (in special, event listeners) works in that sense. The question is, if a event listener is declared inside a function, is it killed when the function ends or it keeps listening?

---

CONTEXT

I have an object `page{}` with a method `battle()`.

In a `choose_action()` method from page, I call `battle()`.

When `battle()` ends, `choose_action` is called again.

`Battle()` have `event.listeners` addressed to buttons with fixed ids ("attack", "defense", etc). When the img with the id "attack" is pressed, the `attack()`(Which is also a `page{}` method) function is called.

My point is, are the `event.listeners` created in `battle()`  global? Or are they  freed when `battle()` ends? I'm afraid calling battle() again will create doubled `attack_event_listeners`, that will make attack (n) times every click, n being the  times `battle()` is called.

Comment: Please don't only explain your code, show it!

Comment: @Teemu I don't have the code at all. That's what i plan do code, i want to know if this works before trying to

Comment: Since i would spend 4+ hours to properly implement all of this.

Comment: You'd already know, if you'd tried ...

Comment: If i discover it fails, i will have spent hours and  won't know how to solve my problem. I'm just giving context. What i want to know is if event listeners called in a function are freed when the function ends.

Comment: It's not a hard question to answer if you know the answer. In c, which i know a little bit, it's easy to answer. If you don't dynamically storage anything you declare on a function, it dies with the function. But c's not javascript, i have no clue how it deals with this kind of thing.

Comment: No, the event listener function is not killed after the attaching function/method has been executed, and the element the event was attached to, continues to listen the event, and when it fires, it executes the attached event handler.

Comment: Can i force the event listener to be  local?

Comment: It doesn't help, this is more related to closures and how the automatic garbage collection works. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?r=SearchResults&s=1|3912.0120

Comment: You can use `removeEventListener` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) at the end of the battle, which should resolve your concern.